# "ifconfig -a" does not show any interfaces

Tags: arm, qemu

I just set up a QEMU image with Ubuntu on ARM64 as per the instructions described [here](http://webkit.sed.hu/blog/20140816/quickndirty-set-aarch64-ubuntu-1404-vm-qemu). However, `ifconfig -a` does not seem to show me an `eth0` or `eth1` interface as I'd expect. Why is that?

```
root@localhost:~# ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your kernel lacks the appropriate driver for your network device (virtio-net, in this case) or for some reason your system image is broken and the driver is not being autoloaded.